# Why does this polynomial transformation not work?

Tags: polynomials, proof-verification

With a little work, one can show that the roots of

$$\left ( \frac{z+i}{z-i} \right )^{2n}=-1 \qquad (*)$$

are $ \pm \cot \left ( \frac{2k-1}{2n} \pi \right )$, where $k=1, 2, 3, ..., n$.

A little arranging of the original equation, and noting that all the odd powers of $z$ cancel out, yields the polynomial of degree $2n$

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{2n}{2k}z^{2n-2k}$$

So the roots of this polynomial must be $ \pm \cot \left ( \frac{2k-1}{2n} \pi \right )$ because this polynomial came from $(*)$ with no loss of degree.

I then made the substitution $x=z^2$, so the polynomial now becomes

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k \binom{2n}{2k}x^{n-k}$$

And as a result of the transformation, the roots should be $\cot^2 \left ( \frac{2k-1}{2n} \pi \right )$ for $k=1, 2, ..., n$.

To test this, I used the case $n=2$. The polynomial becomes

$$\binom{4}{0}x^4-\binom{4}{2}x^2+1 = x^2-6x+1$$

According the the result above, the roots 'should' be $\cot^2 \left ( \frac{\pi}{4}\right ) = 1$ and $\cot^2 \left ( \frac{3\pi}{4}\right )=1$, which is clearly not the case.

Where did I go wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should have
$$\left ( \frac{z+i}{z-i} \right )^{2n}=1$$
in order to have the roots $\pm \cot \left ( \frac{2k-1}{2n} \pi \right ) $ for $k=1, 2, 3, ..., n$. Then, with the same notations, you will obtain the polynomial
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^k \binom{2n}{2k+1}x^{n-1-k}.$$